# Share drive folder to list of user from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script to take a folder from my drive and share it with a list of users.
The script is scheduled to run on a sheet which collects answers from a google form and I set the trigger to run the script at every new submission of the form.

First Attempt. I think there is something wrong with how I create the array containing the list of emails, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

```
function driveShare_array() { 
     var getEmails =[];
     var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var getEmails = sheet.getRange('emailstoshare').getValues(); // emailtoshare is a named range including only the one column where the sheet collects emails from the form submission
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxx'); // added the folder ID in here
      for ( i in getEmails) {
      folder.addViewer(getEmails[i])

      }
    }
```

Second attempt to try to control how the array "getEmails" gets shaped by adding elements (push) one by one

```
   function driveShare_push(){

  var getEmails =[];
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getRange('emailstoshare'); // emailtoshare is a named range including only the one column where the sheet collects emails from the form submission
  for (var i=0;i<range.getNumRows();i++){
      getEmails.push(range.offset(i,0,1,1).getValue());
  }


  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxx'); // added the folder ID in here
 // for ( var j=0;j<range.getNumColumns();j++) {
  for (var j in getEmails){
  folder.addViewer(getEmails[j]) ;
  }
}
```

Both versions (and other variations I have tested) give errors. Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Please specify which errors your code gives you. Also, to troubleshoot yourself it helps to implement logs to see at which point the code is failing and what your values are. For example, before `folder.addViewer(getEmails[j]) ;` add `Logger.log(getEmails[j]);`

Comment: used Logger.log and helped a lot understanding how the data was organised. My code was creating a matrix instead of array. I added the corrected code above for reference. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used logger.log to understand the structure of the data and the code was creating a matrix instead of an array.
Here the corrected code for reference:

```
function driveShare_push(){
  var getEmails =[];
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('emailstoshare');

  for (var i=1;i<range.getNumRows();i++){
    if(range.offset(i, 0, 1, 1).getValue().indexOf("gmail.com") > -1){
    getEmails.push(range.offset(i,0,1,1).getValue());
    }
  }
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxx');
  folder.addViewer(getEmails[getEmails.length-1]) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the email address may not have a Google account and thus the folder could not be shared with them. You might consider adding a try/catch block to ignore such errors.

```
function driveShare_array() { 
  var getEmails =[];
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxx'); 
  var getEmails = sheet.getRange('emailstoshare').getValues();
  getEmails.forEach(function(email) {
    if (/\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) {
      try {
        folder.addViewer(email)
      } catch (f) {
        Logger.log("Cannot share with " + email);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm testing this submitting the form from a gmail account and it doesn't run. I have also tried to manually add the email in the code like this:   folder.addViewer('xxx@gmail.com');  instead of using the for cycle and this way it works. That's why I was assuming there is an issue with the way I'm creating/reading  the array and moving through it with the index.

Answer (score 0):

If your triggering the function with onFormSubmit trigger then you can do something like this.

```
function driveShare_array(e) { 
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxx');
  folder.addViewer(e.namedValues['Email Address']); 
}
```

You will probably want to store them on some spreadsheet and retrieve them to make sure you haven’t already added it to the list. You will need to create an onFormSubmit trigger for the function in script editor Edit/Project Triggers.

Comment: how would you define "e"?  I have a vertical named range that identifies the single column where new emails appear on each form submission. how should I organise this into a list of values that I can feed to addviewer?

Comment: It is the trigger event it’s passed to the function from the onformsubmit trigger. Go to the guide page of the documentation and on the bottom left side of the page you’ll see event objects look at the onformsubmit object for a spreadsheet